# Angular pagination variables in controller functions and view

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
function PostListController($timeout) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.posts = [];
  vm.pagination = { pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 9 };

  vm.init = function () {
    load();  
  };

  vm.load = function () {
    // load posts from service
  };

};
```

On the HTML I have buttons for next and previous pages and buttons for page numbers ...

1. Should I add pageNumber and pageSize as arguments to load?
   Or should I use the vm variables and no arguments ...
2. Should I add nextPage, setPage and previousPage and a watch to pageNumber and pageSize scope variables to check if there are changes?
3. Or maybe changing vm.pagination.pageNumber and other variables on click in the html code?

I am not sure that is the standard way to do this ...

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use [angular-ui-bootstrap's pagination component](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass the page direction as an argument to the `load()` function. Let the function access the `vm.pagination` and get the results.
2. No
3. You can't do it since you don't know the size of the result set when in HTML.

   function PostListController($timeout) {

   ```
    var vm = this;

    vm.posts = [];
    vm.pagination = { pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 9 };

    vm.init = function () {
      load("next");  
    };

    vm.load = function (direction) {

      // Use the argument and vm.pagination in conjunction to decide the result set  
      // load posts from service
    };
   ```

   };